# Converting unicode to human readable format in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, type-conversion

Im getting this data from a service .

> Name = "MAYA BAZAAR (
>   \U00e3\U0192\U017e\U00e3\U0192\U00a4\U00e3\U0192\U0090\U00e3\U201a\U00b6\U00e3\U0192\U00bc\U00e3\U0192\U00ab
>   )  ";

when this is put into a label it looks like this 
MAYA BAZAAR ( ãƒžãƒ¤ãƒã‚¶ãƒ¼ãƒ« )

What it should actually look like is 
MAYA BAZAAR ( マヤバザール )  which is in japanese.

I have tried many ways of encoding but of no use. The code i use is

```
if var x = self.listArray[indexPath.row]["Name"]! as? String{
hd = NSString(string: x)
hd = NSString(format: "%@\n", hd)
}
```

I am using alamofire for downloading the data . The function call is

```
func getMyService2 (input: String,  paramaterslist : Dictionary     <String, String> ,completion :(result: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>], error: NSError?) -> Void){        

         Alamofire.request(.GET,input,parameters:paramaterslist).responseJSON(){}
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the data? The encoding is clearly incorrect at some stage of the process...

Comment: Did you also send that data to that service?

Comment: This looks as if UTF-8 data was converted to a string using the NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding (Windows-1252) encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your data is wrong.
"\u30de\u30e4\u30d0\u30b6\u30fc\u30eb" = "マヤバザール"
"\U00e3\U0192\U017e\U00e3\U0192\U00a4\U00e3\U0192\U0090\U00e3\U201a\U00b6\U00e3\U0192\U00bc\U00e3\U0192\U00ab" = " ãƒžãƒ¤ãƒã‚¶ãƒ¼ãƒ«"

So, your code is right, you can use it to read Unicode data.

Comment: It was the a problem from server .